# LOL launcher doesnt want to start (PoL)

Tags: wine, launcher, games, playonlinux

I've a little problem, when I try to run League of Legends from PlayOnLinux I receive an error:

[image]

I don't really understand why it doesn't work and I can't see detailed information (doesn't want to show, take long time to load I guess) .

Wine is installed and I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Patcher GUI will crash on all versions of WINE newer than v1.6.

Click on `create shortcut` and point it to `LeagueClient.exe`. Remove the existing shortcut to the patcher.

LeagueClient will automatically call the patcher (sans GUI) if it's required to update the game client.

Also note that on rare occasions, the LeagueClientRenderer may also hang. If this happens, simply end the process and restart LeagueClient.

Answer (score 0):

You know that League Of Legends has a Snap package.
Just install that and forget about PlayOnLinux and Wine.
Had the same problem as you but using Lutris and found that changing the Wine version from Lutris app resolved the problem. Took me about half a day to figure out what was the problem and what Wine version worked( lol is very picky on wine version)
 But after i installed LoL from snap was super simple.
Good luck.

Comment: Where did you get LoL? I couldn't find it in the games section of the [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/store).